# While hitting anchor tag, getting route not defined error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

*Laravel Route:*

```
Route::post('verify-phone', [LoginController::class, 'verifyPhone'])->name('verify-phone');
```

```
<a href="{{route('verify-phone')}}" >Resend OTP</a>
```

Comment: because anchor tags uses get methods, while you define your route as post

Answer (score 1):

You should use form if you are using post request then it works fine

```
<form action="{{route('/verify-phone')}}" method="POST">
<a type="submit"> Resend Otp </a>
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below. Since this route is `a href` tag so use `Route::get()`

```
Route::get('verify-phone', [LoginController::class, 'verifyPhone'])->name('verify-phone')
```